# Como alterar ícone de cursor do mouse ao passar em cima do link?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, dbgrid

**Informações:** Tenho uma tabela com os dados de funcionários. Há uma coluna desta tabela, onde estão contidos os emails, eles possuem um link que abre direto no *Outlook*.

O componente que estou utilizando em minha tabela é o `DBGrid`.

**Objetivo:** Gostaria de trocar o ícone do cursor do mouse quando ele estiver passando por cima do link, indicando que o email possui um link.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual versão do Delphi você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando a versão XE4

Comment: Certo, e qual é este componente "Tabela" que você está utilizando? não seria uma grid?

Comment: estou usando DBGrid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Navegue até a aba de eventos de sua `DBGrid` e clique duas vezes em `OnMouseMove`. O Delphi automaticamente criará o evento, você irá checar a coordenada `X` que seria a horizontal portanto seria a coluna, portanto você deve saber qual seria a coluna que consta os links dos emails, e se por exemplo fosse a coluna `3` ele verificaria se estivesse vazio e setaria o Cursor, veja como funcionaria:

Você tem primeiramente que declarar um `Type` para poder acessar as propriedades privadas:

```delphi
type
    THackGrid = class(TCustomDBGrid); //criar uma nova classe pra acessar as propriedades privadas
```

E aqui a função do `MouseMove`:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,  Y: Integer);
var
  pt: TGridcoord;
  MouseScrPt : TPoint;
  OrigActiveRecord : integer;
begin
  pt:= DBGrid1.MouseCoord(x, y);

  if dgTitles in DBGrid1.Options    then  Dec(pt.y); //se o titulo é mostrado então ajusta a row index(-1) para nao dar erro de argument out of range
  if dgIndicator in DBGrid1.Options then  Dec(pt.x); //se o indicador é mostrado então ajusta a column index (-1) para nao dar erro de argument out of range

    if THackGrid(DBGrid1).DataLink.Active and (pt.y>=0) and (pt.x>=3)  then
    begin
       THackGrid(DBGrid1).DataLink.ActiveRecord:= pt.y;
       if (DBGrid1.Columns[pt.x].Field.AsString <> '') and (pt.x=3) then
         DBGrid1.Cursor:=crHandPoint
       else
         DBGrid1.Cursor:=crDefault;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 pela simplicidade.

Comment: Muito bom...obrigado, teria como eu verificar se o campo esta vazio ? Caso aquela pessoa não tenho cadastrado o email o cursor continuasse normal?

Comment: Pronto @Edder . veja como verificar atualizei a solução

Answer (score 1):

Melhor: Inserir o código `Screen.Cursor:= crHandPoint` no evento `OnMouseMove`;
No demais, fora do campo, `Screen.Cursor:= crHandPoint` ;