# Hyperlink em um campo do DBGrid

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Eu estou fazendo um pequeno software interno para pesquisar ramais em minha empresa. Além dos ramais eu também coloquei um campo de email no banco de dados como pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu intuito é ao clicar sobre o e-mail cadastrado, o software através do `ShellExecute` abrir uma janela para enviar o e-mail. Eu estou utilizando a opção `dgRowSelect` como `TRUE` e por causa disso o evento `OnCellClick` não identifica corretamente qual célula foi clicada.

Nas minhas buscas não encontrei ainda nenhuma maneira de fazer. Então eu pensei em utilizar um `TLabel` dentro do campo. Eu posso colocar o `ShellExecute` no evento `OnClick` do `TLabel` e mudar também o ícone do cursor do mesmo.

Se o TLabel for uma boa solução, como inserir TLabel nas células de uma coluna no DBGrid?

Ou qual seria uma outra boa solução?

Comment: Eu reformulei totalmente a pergunta para ficar mais claro meu objetivo.

Comment: Teria algum problema em usar o evento [onCellClick](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.OnCellClick) do TDBGrid?

Comment: Caro @DanielGrillo, poderia postar como resolveu o problema? Grato!

Answer (score 1):

Veja minha unit:

```pascal
unit untMainForm;

interface

uses
  WinApi.Windows,
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils,
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    dbgLink: TDBGrid;
    cdsLink: TClientDataSet;
    dasLink: TDataSource;
    cdsLinkID: TIntegerField;
    cdsLinkLink: TStringField;
    lblCoord: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure dbgLinkMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure dbgLinkCellClick(Column: TColumn);
  private
    mouseCell: TGridCoord;
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  nI: Integer;
begin
  cdsLink.CreateDataSet;

  for nI := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    cdsLink.Append;
    cdsLinkID.AsInteger := nI;
    cdsLinkLink.AsString := 'fake@fake.com.br ' + IntToStr(nI);
  end;

  cdsLink.Post;
end;

procedure TMainForm.dbgLinkMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  mouseCell := dbgLink.MouseCoord(X,Y);
  if mouseCell.X = 2 then
    Screen.Cursor := crHandPoint
  else
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;

  lblCoord.Caption := Format('Coordenadas X: %d, Y: %d', [mouseCell.X, mouseCell.Y]);
end;

procedure TMainForm.dbgLinkCellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  if mouseCell.X = 2 then
  begin
    ShowMessage(Format('Coluna: %d', [mouseCell.X]));
  end;
end;

initialization
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;

end.
```

fonte: http://drgarcia1986.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/dicas-sobre-o-componente-dbgrid-do-delphi/

O método `dbgLink.MouseCoord(X,Y);` retorna a celula em coordenadas também de acordo com a posição do mouse passada pelo evento `OnMouseMove`.

Comment: Veja também essa outra pergunta aqui no StackOverflow BR: [como-alterar-icone-de-cursor-do-mouse-ao-passar-em-cima-do-link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5405/como-alterar-icone-de-cursor-do-mouse-ao-passar-em-cima-do-link)